# How do I verify two post requests to the same url but with different bodies in Wiremock?

Tags: java, wiremock

How do I verify two post requests to the same url but with different bodies in Wiremock? The same url should be called once with body 1 and once with body 2.

As it is now Wiremock only cares about verifying the last line.

```java
verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/my-url"))
    .withRequestBody(equalToJson(resourceAsString("my-first-body.json"), true, false)));

verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/my-url"))
    .withRequestBody(equalToJson(resourceAsString("my-other-body.json"), true, false)));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661054/wiremock-multiple-responses-for-the-same-url-and-content duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661054/wiremock-multiple-responses-for-the-same-url-and-content is about generating different responses for the same request, this question is about verifying different request bodies sent to the same URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```java
var postRequests = findAll(postRequestedFor(urlMatching("/my-url")));

assertThat(postRequests.get(0).getBodyAsString()).isEqualTo(resourceAsString("my-first-body.json"));
assertThat(postRequests.get(1).getBodyAsString()).isEqualTo(resourceAsString("my-other-body.json"));
```

Comment: If you wanted to make this order indifferent, could you modify your `postRequests` to be two separate variables that have the `equalToJson` filtering, and then verify that they are a certain size?

Comment: I guess you could use the anyMatch method for both of the files on the postRequests list.